# How to use the NOW() function as upper bound of a range?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, range, range-types

I have a table with a column of type `tstzrange` in a Postgres 10.6 database.
I need to insert / update rows with a defined lower bound but the value of the current time for the upper bound of the range, so `NOW()` as upper value.

Have tried things like:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET date_range = ['2018-03-23 00:00:00-05', now())
WHERE id = 3;
```

Is there a way to use a built-in function or a subquery maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a ***range constructor***. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT)

> Each range type has a constructor function with the same name as the
>   range type. Using the constructor function is frequently more
>   convenient than writing a range literal constant, since it avoids the
>   need for extra quoting of the bound values. The constructor function
>   accepts two or three arguments. The two-argument form constructs a
>   range in standard form (lower bound inclusive, upper bound exclusive),
>   while the three-argument form constructs a range with bounds of the
>   form specified by the third argument. The third argument must be one
>   of the strings “`()`”, “`(]`”, “`[)`”, or “`[]`”.

So:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    date_range = tstzrange('2018-03-23 00:00:00-05', now())
WHERE  id = 3;
```

I assume you are aware that `now()` resolves to the start time of the transaction.

- [Difference between now() and current_timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3684)

Comment: Surprisingly enough `select '[2018-03-23 00:00:00-05,now)'::tstzrange` and `select '[2018-03-23 00:00:00-05,now()'::tstzrange` works too, but `select '[2018-03-23 00:00:00-05,now())'::tstzrange` does not. (Reason for the first two in the linked question).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Thank you. I couldn't accept it earlier. It's now accepted!