# How to use BETWEEN condition for array column in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, operators, between, date-range

I have a `multiple_dates` column in a Postgres DB.
To find by a specific date I'm writing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM companies
WHERE  '2019-06-30' = ANY (multiple_dates)
```

But I want to search by a specific period by using `BETWEEN` clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM companies
WHERE  (ANY (multiple_dates) BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30')  -- pseudo-code
```

This SQL didn't work. How can I use `ANY` and `BETWEEN` clause at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "problem" is that the [`ANY` *construct*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) works for *operators*, not for other *constructs* - and `BETWEEN` is another *construct*.

Related:

- [Can IS DISTINCT FROM be combined with ANY or ALL somehow?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/60342/3684)

There is an **easy solution** for this, though. Construct a [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) from the given bounds and use the [contains operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE).

Related:

- [How to use the NOW() function as upper bound of a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690533/how-to-use-the-now-function-as-upper-bound-of-a-range/56690941#56690941)

Then the query can simply be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   companies
WHERE  daterange('2019-06-01', '2019-06-30', '[]') @> ANY (multiple_dates)
```

Note the third argument `'[]'` to construct the range with *inclusive* bounds to match the behavior of `BETWEEN`.

---

**Alternative:** normalize your schema. Create a n:1 table like:

```
CREATE TABLE company_date
   company_id  int NOT NULL REFERENCES companies
 , single_date date NOT NULL
 , PRIMARY KEY (company_id, single_date)
);
```

Add an index on `(single_date, company_id)` as well. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Then your query can be:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   companies c
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM company_date cd
   WHERE  single_date BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30'
   AND    cd.company_id = c.company_id
   );
```

Occupies more space on disk, more verbose query, but much faster for big tables and more versatile.